# Sending multiple CC's and BCCs with PHP PEAR MAIL

Tags: php, email, pear

I have a project that I am working on at my job and I am using Pear's mailing.  I need to use smtp because we need to be able to track everything from our mailserver.  And users need to be able to log in before sending a company based email.  We cannot use php's mail function fo this.

My problem is that I cant find any documentation on the net for sending CC and Bcc as well as sending multiple BCCs.  It is very easy to do with php' mail funciton .  All you do is add it to the $header variable like so

```
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";
```

This is my code for the php function where I use PEAR

```
function sender_mail($email,$subject,$mailmsg, $cc, $bcc){

    include("Mail.php");
    /* mail setup recipients, subject etc */

    //DEFAULT VALUE OF FROM 
    $from = "noreply@addata.net";

    //GET EMAIL OF USER
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT email, email_pass FROM u_perinfo WHERE user_id = '$_SESSION[uid]'")
    or die("There was an error when grabbing your email information");
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        if($row[0] != ''){
            $from = $row[0];
        }
        $email_pass = $row[1];
    }

    $recipients = "$email";
    $headers["From"] = "$from";
    $headers["To"] = "$email";
    $headers["Subject"] = $subject;
    $headers["Cc"] = "$cc";  //Line added by Me to see if it works
    $headers["Bcc"] = "$bcc";  //Line added by Me to see if it works


    //$mailmsg = "Welcome to Addatareference.com! \r\n\r\nBelow is your unique login information.  \r\n\r\n(Please do not share your login information.)$accountinfo";
    /* SMTP server name, port, user/passwd */
    $smtpinfo["host"] = "smtp.emailsrvr.com";
    $smtpinfo["port"] = "25";
    $smtpinfo["auth"] = true;
    $smtpinfo["username"] = "$from";
    $smtpinfo["password"] = "$email_pass";
    /* Create the mail object using the Mail::factory method */
    $mail_object =& Mail::factory("smtp", $smtpinfo);
    /* Ok send mail */
    $mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $mailmsg);

}
```

I have been trying to find a solution to this with no real info coming back my way.  If someone could help me out with this I would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't know what that Mail.php you're using is, but I'd suggest using PHPMailer (http://phpmailer.worxware.com) or Swiftmailer (http://swiftmailer.org) instead.

Comment: Have you tried adding all email addresses including the bcc and cc addresses to the recipients list and then specifying the cc and bcc addresses in the headers?

Comment: Also, are you able to send mail from the system. Your host might be blocking port 25

Comment: I'm pretty sure @jrod has the answer here. Put every address you're sending to in the recipients list, and use the headers to distinguish between 'To', 'Cc', and 'Bcc'.

Comment: Seems a mighty bizarre way to structure the choice of addresses. Took me ages to work out what the hell was going on. I guess I coulda rtfm. Yeah right.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have you tried to add multiple addresses "," separated?

```
$headers['Cc'] = 'cc@example.com, bb@example.com, dd@ex.com';
```

This might work, according to [line 218 in the source](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/docs/latest/__filesource/fsource_Mail__Mail-1.2.0Mail.php.html#a218).

Answer (score 26):

There is a problem with Bcc though when using the PEAR Mail function: Thunderbird displays the Bcc header, so the recipient is not hidden, which is the whole point of Bcc. It is also displayed in the To: header list (since you have to include the Bcc list in recipients).

Edit: SOLVED - I found from another site that the solution is just to include the Bcc list in the $recipients, and not in any of the headers. It works!

Thus:

```
$bcc = "foo@example.com";
$to = "bar@example.com";
$headers = array(..other stuff.., 'To' => $to, ..rest of header stuff); // No Bcc header!
$recipients = $to.", ".$bcc;
$mail = $smtp->send($recipients, $headers, $message);
```

Edit #2: Acknowledging my source - http://raamdev.com/2008/adding-cc-recipients-with-pear-mail/

Comment: Thanks for the source credit. :) (I realize my thank you is a bit late, but better late than never!)

Comment: this is the better answer. I just tested it too and got it working. Up until now (and this answer) I could not solve the bcc issue.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not a true Bcc though, right?  It's just sending multiple email messages.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to add all to, cc, bcc in $recipients variable. Header decides where to send.

Comment: can you give an example ?