# PHP email send to, cc and bcc

Tags: php, email

I have PHP Email

```
$host = 'smtp.office365.com';
$port = '587';
$username = 'donotreply@test.com';
$password = 'sew004?';

$headers = array(
    'Port'          => $port,
    'From'          => $from,
    'To'            => $to,
    'Subject'       => $subject,
    'Content-Type'  => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
);

$recipients = $to.", ".$cc.", ".$bcc;

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
    array ('host' => $host,
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password));

    $mail = $smtp->send($recipients, $headers, $body);

    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
         echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
    } else {
         echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
    }
```

Now I can't send it if I using this function:

```
$recipients = $to.", ".$cc.", ".$bcc;
```

But if I remove one of them:

```
$recipients = $to.", ".$cc;
```

It can work perfect.

But now I want, I can send email to, cc and bcc.

Comment: maybe help https://stackoverflow.com/a/14559602/3615630

Comment: What are the values in `$cc` and `$bcc`?

Comment: @MilanChheda of course email Sir

Comment: Okay, looking at the docs for Pear Mail, please use something else :P (e.g. PHPMailer)